# R patchwork package trouble displaying many plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, visualization, patchwork

I am enjoying the `patchwork` package quite a bit and I am generally happy with even its default formatting.

However, I cannot figure out how to get a reasonable result when trying to display many plots. The output is unreadable (plots shrunk down and dominated by text) and the saved output is completely blank.

#### Input:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(patchwork)

plots <- list()
testfunction <- function(x) {
  plot_placeholder <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
                      geom_point(aes(mpg, disp)) + 
                      ggtitle(paste("p", x, sep = ""))
  plots[[length(plots) + 1]] <<- plot_placeholder
}

mapply(testfunction, c(1:66), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)


patchwork::wrap_plots(plots)
ggsave("test.pdf")
```

#### Output:

[image]

Is there a way within `patchwork` to make the page larger or wrap plots across multiple pages of a PDF? Or is there a different package that may help with this?

---

## Update:

[Maurits Evers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6530970/maurits-evers) pointed out that this is an issue with my arguments in `ggsave()`, not `patchwork`. With these changes the plots look much better in the .pdf output, but were still being truncated at the bottom of page 1. From `this post`, found the last bit of change needed to generate desired results

#### Input:

```
# ...

pdf()
patchwork::wrap_plots(plots) 
ggsave("test.pdf", width = 20, height = 20)
dev.off()
```

#### Output:

[image]

Comment: This is not an issue with `patchwork` but with the resolution & size of your PDF plot. Try increasing the plot size in `ggsave`, e.g. `ggsave("test.pdf", width = 20, height = 10)` to see the effect, and then change values to something that suits your need.

Comment: ^ +1. You might also look at https://www.christophenicault.com/post/understand_size_dimension_ggplot2/  for more on how to work with text sizes in ggplot2.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense and looks much better already. The last of the charts are being truncated though, I edited the original post to include a screenshot

Comment: Figured out the last bit of change I needed! Thanks all - looks great!